# añadir nuevo campo a un Combobox usando datos de un Json

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, xmlhttprequest

Intente muchas cosas pero no lo logro.
Tengo un objeto Json devuelto de una consulta `XMLhttpRequest`

Lo que quiero hacer es cargar un comboBox con los datos devueltos.

Estoy usando un forEach para segmentar los datos, pero, el problema es que no se como adicionar los campos al comboBox

```
let especialidades = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            especialidades.forEach(especialidad => {
                getElementById('Especialidad').innerHTML = "<option value='"+especialidad.ID+"'>"+especialidad.especialidad+"</option>"
            });
```

Estoy usando esto, pero obvio en cada nueva iteracion cambia el contenido del ComboBox y al final solo queda un campo. Lo que quiero es que aumenten los campos, no que solo quede uno.

Answer (score 1):

Bien, después de buscar un poco mas de información he encontrado una solución.

```
let especialidades = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

var input = document.getElementById('Especialidad');
var i = 0;

especialidades.forEach(especialidad => {

    i = i+1;
    input.options[i]   = new Option(especialidad.especialidad,especialidad.ID);
});
```

Creo que el codigo se explica solo.